# How many inches of dirt depth required to grow grass?

Tags: grass, container-gardening

I want to grow a container of grass on my balcony for my dog. How many inches of depth of soil is typically required to grow healthy grass? Length and width of the container I’ll determine at a later date but wanted to know the depth requirement to get a solid foundation for grass to grow.

Comment: What will the dog do with the grass?

Comment: Likely just lay/roll around/sleep on it.